# nodejs.TypeError: next is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am new to typescript.
Now I want to get api response information(include `Elapsed time`, `response status`, `api route`).I just found a middleware in github[response-time](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time). I just simply used this middleware when boot up.

```
export default (app: Application) => {
  //some code here
  var responseTime = require('response-time')
  app.use(responseTime(function (req, res, time) {
    //some code here
  }))
  
};
```

when I `npm run dev`, I got

```
2020-07-30 11:28:21,929 ERROR 85820 [-/127.0.0.1/-/1ms GET /favicon.ico] nodejs.TypeError: next is not a function
    at responseTime (/Users/lithium/develop/one-authentication-center/node_modules/response-time/index.js:61:12)
    at dispatch (/Users/lithium/develop/one-authentication-center/node_modules/koa/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
    at /Users/lithium/develop/one-authentication-center/node_modules/koa/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:34:12
    at MidwayApplication.handleRequest (/Users/lithium/develop/one-authentication-center/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:166:12)
    at MidwayApplication.handleRequest (/Users/lithium/develop/one-authentication-center/node_modules/egg/lib/application.js:211:18)
    at Server.handleRequest (/Users/lithium/develop/one-authentication-center/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:148:19)
    at Server.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:777:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)

pid: 85820
```

I opened response-time/index.js, the code raised error is

```
  var fn = typeof opts !== 'function'
    ? createSetHeader(opts)
    : opts

  return function responseTime (req, res, next) {
    var startAt = process.hrtime()

    onHeaders(res, function onHeaders () {
      var diff = process.hrtime(startAt)
      var time = diff[0] * 1e3 + diff[1] * 1e-6

      fn(req, res, time)
    })

    next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the next of responseTime but a string or date/number , i see there ''time'' as third not sure what "some code here" does but seems is trying to call next on time

Comment: I passed `next` as last argument, `responseTime(function (req, res, time, next))`, it failed with same error.Anyway, I found another solution to report metrics to influxdb.Thanks for your answer.